# JLabel not displaying image after choosing from jFileChooser in java netbeans IDE 8.02

Tags: java, swing

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 to create my project application. I have created my application's signup page using multiple panels in `CardLayout`. For users to upload their image I created a `JLabel` and added `mouseClicked` event to it which displays `JFileChooser` but the image chosen is not displayed in the label (even though the image path is stored). Please check the following code.

```java
private void PrImgLabMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser FileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int response = FileChooser.showOpenDialog(Panel1);
    if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File imgFile = FileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        String Filepath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
        ImgMeth.Resize(Filepath, PrImgLab);
    }
    else if(response == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION);{
        Icon defimg = new ImageIcon("DefImg.png"); //default image path
        PrImgLab.setIcon(defimg);
    }
}
```

This the label event class and the code below is the method used to resize the image and fit it into the `JLabel`.

```
public void Resize(String path,JLabel label){
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(path);
    Image image  = img.getImage();
    Image imgScale = image.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    
    label.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Comment: Consider creating and posting a valid [mre] program in your question. The link will tell the details. Also, please read the [ask] link.

Comment: If you do `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));`, does it display the image?

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions to make reading your code easier.

Comment: After calling `resize` (Yes that should begin [lower case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)) call `validate` on the `Container` containing the label.

Comment: I see an error in the following line of your code (in method `PrImgLabMouseClicked`): `else if(response == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION);{` If this is your actual code then you need to remove the semicolon character, i.e. `;`

Comment: @g00se the validate method worked...now the image is showing. Ty everyone

Comment: OK. Shall post it as an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `resize` ([Yes that should begin lower case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)) call `validate` on the `Container` containing the label.